# Firefox with Capybara and Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Cucumber with Capybara and Selenium-Webdriver. Until now, I've always used Chrome but the project has requested some cross browser tests for Firefox too.

When running in Firefox, I just get a blank window and webpage doesn't appear.

This is the error I get:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: no sessionId in returned payload
```

My setup is:

```
Firefox V54
Cucumber 2.4
Selenium-webdriver 3.4.0
geckodriver 0.17
```

My firefox profile:

```
if ENV['firefox']
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    options = {
        :js_errors => false,
            }
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
  end
```

Any ideas why I only get a blank window when Firefox starts up in the test?

Comment: check https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3621 . "The 3.0.5 error is because of firefox updating to 52. AFAIK capybara does not install geckodriver. Sounds like you'll need to force install the latest version of geckodriver as well"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim to be running geckodriver v0.17 (which should work with the other versions you list) however that error would imply you're not.  Try running `bundle exec geckodriver --version` and seeing what it returns.  I'm guessing you've got a gem installed that attempts to manage the download of geckodriver and an older version is actually being used when you run your tests.  If that is the case check with the specific gem documentation on how to update the installed geckodriver.

Comment: I've got the executable for Geckodriver0.17 on my path.  When running that Bundler command, I get the following:    connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Comment: @Tom The fact that you get that output tells me you do have one of the gems that manages geckodriver installed either in your bundle or in your system gems, and it's probably not updating to 0.17 correctly.  When run,  Bundler amends your path to prefer gem provided binaries over your system path and it looks like that's what's happening to you.  Look for gems like `webdrivers`, `geckodriver-helper`, etc either in your bundle or system gems.  Uninstall or force them to updated the installed geckodriver and then retry.

Comment: I've got it to work.  I'm now faced with an untrusted connection page.  Do you know how I could amend my profile to ignore this message so that I can bypass this page?

Comment: @Tom There's an `accept_insecure_certs` you can set on the capabilities you pass during driver registration, but that's really a separate question than this one.  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/capabilities.rb#L50

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll start a new question. The Firefox config has changed considerably since the last time I needed it.

Comment: @Tom  You're welcome, don't forget to mark this question as answered